# Assign value from api response to specific model object in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a `Contact` model that has three attributes:

`name, email, id`

`name` and `email` are both present, but `id` is null.

I am using `name` and `email` to pass in through an API Post call, and this is the response I get back:

```
{"count": 1, "next": null, "previous": null, "results": [
  {"id": 8067950, "name": "Bill","email": "test@test.com"}]}
```

My loop looks like this:

```
contacts_array.each do |contact|
  api_call(contact.name, contact.email)
end
```

`contacts_array` is an array of ruby objects, namely `Contact` models. How can I, within that loop, assign the response `id` I get back to the contact used in the `api_call`?

Comment: So your `api_call` call returns a string or a Ruby Hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really understand the difference between your `Person` and `Contact` model, but I'll assume they're the same model.

Generally you should know that it's a bad idea to handle the field called `id` on your own in rails. If you insist on storing the id which is returned from the call, then you should store it in another field, like `api_id` for example.

Below is a code that should work fine if `api_call` returns a Ruby Hash like the one in your question.

```
contacts_array.each do |contact|
  contact.api_id = api_call(contact.name, contact.email)['results'].first['id']
end
```